# Restrict the user from adding more than one event under the same time-period in Dayview of Fullcalender

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can somebody help me to find the way, how to restrict the user from adding more than one event under the same time-period in Dayview of Fullcalender?  [See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkfEn.png)

In the image, it can be seen that user is the part of two event namely "1" and "2" between 7:00 am to 8:00 am..

All i need is I want to restrict the user while user add another event after adding one..

Comment: Can you post the code? We can't help you out if we don't know how it currently works.

Comment: If you are using a particular library, please link to that library somehow... looks like Fullcalender is a JQuery library

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: This is the open-source plug-in i am using..

Comment: you would be able to see this html page with the name "selectable.html"